# How to Fade out background-color of a div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a div background color to fadeOut slow

**html**

```
<div class="bg">...........</div>
```

I used this jquery

```
$('.bg').css('backgroundColor','#dedede');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.bg').css('backgroundColor','#ffffff'); 
}, 1000);
```

How to add the fadeOut effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fadeOut`:
    $('.bg').css('backgroundColor', '#dedede');

```
$('.bg').fadeOut(1000);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/eL6k87pv/)

**OR**

You can `animate`:

```
$('.bg').animate({
    'opacity': '0'
}, 1000);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/eL6k87pv/1/)

**UPDATE**

```
$('.bg').css('backgroundColor', '#dedede');
$('.bg').animate({
    'opacity': '0.5'
}, 1000, function () {
    $('.bg').css({
        'backgroundColor': '#fff',
        'opacity': '1'
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/eL6k87pv/2/)

Comment: But the problem, this fadeOut effect hide all the div element, not just the background color !!

Comment: I want the text stay still and don't fadeOut too